# Conditional Filtering breaks with whitespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter

I'm retrieving a subset of database records based on user-entered criteria.

Searching by name successfully retrieves all records containing the string ONLY if the string is one word without whitespace. When adding another word or a space it returns an empty result.

Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(ProductSearchModel searchModel)
    {
        var result = db.Products.AsQueryable();
        if (searchModel != null)
        {
            if (searchModel.Id.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.ProductId == searchModel.Id);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Colour))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Colour.Contains(searchModel.Colour));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Brand))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Brand.Contains(searchModel.Brand));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Genre))
                result = result.Where(x => x.Genre.Contains(searchModel.Genre));

            if (searchModel.PriceFrom.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price >= searchModel.PriceFrom);
            if (searchModel.PriceTo.HasValue)
                result = result.Where(x => x.Price <= searchModel.PriceTo);
        }
        return result.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Section of view (implementation of all fields same as Model.Name):

```
<div class="row">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" id="advancedSearchToggle"></span>
</div>

...

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are searching with and what types of results you want it to match?

Comment: I search "Water" and it returns "Water Green", "Water Blue", "Water Yellow". 
If I search "Water " with whitespace at the end, it returns nothing.
If I search "Water Green" it returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that the type of whitespace in your search string is the same as in the DB?  Is it possible that the DB contains something with tabs instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and remove the spaces.

result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ","").Contains(searchModel.Name));

Comment: The spaces are in the `searchModel.Name` as well.

Comment: I would remove those as well. result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ","").Contains(searchModel.Name.Replace(" ","")));

Comment: That worked if I also add replace to the searchModel.Name:
`result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ", "").Contains(searchModel.Name.Replace(" ", "")));`

Comment: You can also take a look and see what the sql generated by entity framework looks like by: context.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s); You may want to create your own sql or call a stored procedure.